# SQL SERVER 2008 new query window insert float using comma (,)

Tags: sql-server, ssms

For some things I use *new query window* in our MS SQL Management Studio (Version: 10.0.1600.22 (SQL_PreRelease).080709-1414).

I try to insert some data, and I can not use comma (,) when I try to insert float value.
If I use dot (.) then value is multiplied by 1000 - and I don't want that.

Any hint would be greatly appreciated ;)

Edit: here is the query:

```
USE MyDatabase
INSERT INTO MyTable (value1, value2, value3, [timestamp])
VALUES (15233, 286, TroublesomeValue, DATEADD(HOUR, 9, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))
```

If TroublesomeValue = 1.1 then 1100 will be inserted. I can not use 1,1 because comma separates values. I tried (1,1) or [1,1] but no success :(

Comment: Can we see your query?

Comment: Can you please sepcify the column name where you have added float value or some data?

Comment: Oh, sorry, 3rd column (TroublesomeValue) is declared as decimal(10, 3).

Comment: How come you are having duplicated field name `value1` in the insert query? Is this the real query?

Comment: I changed names, thanks for notifying me ;) Updated my question.

Comment: Your query [works fine in the fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/31df5/1). It must be something else doing it. Do you have any insert triggers running?

Comment: I'm not aware of programming languages that are locale-dependent in their literals. SQL is not locale-dependent, too. Are you actually using a number, `1.1`, or a string, `'1.1'`?

Comment: I am not using any program language in this case, I am running query directly on server using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. I am using number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast or convert you value to a float:

```
CAST('1.1' AS FLOAT)
```

If you still have problems try to change you Regional settings

Comment: Casting is working exactly as it should, as it encapsulates value with brackets. Should of think of this before, thanks ;)